# Does the indeterminacy (uncertainty) of energy and momentum used to calculate mass cause indeterminacy of gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, energy, gravity, momentum

General relativity is considered deterministic. However, the "mass" of an object as defined by modern physics is a calculation based on using measurements of the object's energy and momentum. And quantum mechanics indicates the indeterminacy (uncertainty) of the evolution of any quantum system. Therefore, the evolution of mass is indeterminate. And I imagine the indeterminacy of mass makes general relativity indeterminate. This leads to my question: "Does the indeterminacy (uncertainty) of energy and momentum used to calculate mass cause indeterminacy of gravity?"

Also, I clarify two points:

1. This question assumes the indeterminacy of the evolution of a quantum system.
2. This question sets aside the possibility of quantum gravity.

Comment: If the initial problem is well posed, the evolution of quantum states is as deterministic as dynamics in curved space time. It's the wave function collapse which introduces "randomness" in quantum mechanical picture. It's a question of how one would reconcile quantum mechanical measurement in a general relativistic framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite your second clarification point, this is probably one of the most common arguments in favor of the quantization of gravity.

General relativity is described by the Einstein Field Equations, which read
$$G_{ab} = 8 \pi T_{ab},$$
with $G_{ab}$ being the Einstein tensor, describing curvature, and $T_{ab}$ being the stress-energy-momentum tensor, describing classical matter. The simplest modification one can make to this equation to consider quantum matter (and hence allow for quantum effects, such as uncertainty principles and superpositions) is to consider matter to be composed of quantum fields and write the Semiclassical Einstein Equation,
$$G_{ab} = 8 \pi \langle \hat{T}_{ab} \rangle,$$
where $\hat{T}_{ab}$ is now the stress-energy-momentum operator associated with the quantum fields and $$\langle \cdot \rangle$ denote the expectation value in the quantum state (notice the Einstein equations now also play a role in determining allowed quantum states).

This is sort of a natural idea, but it has some curious effects. Suppose, for example, that one makes a Schrödinger-cat-like experiment with the Earth. If a certain radioactive isotope decays, a device explodes the Earth and sends its debris far away. If the isotope doesn't decay, the Earth keeps going on happily. Notice that now, in a certain sense, you managed to put the whole planet in a superposition. The question is: what is the gravitational pull felt by the Moon? Is that of a spherical planet or of shattered debris? Is it the average between both? If the superposition is suddenly resolved, does the gravitational pull that the Moon feels suddenly collapse too?

It is difficult, to say the least, to understand how a classical gravitational field would be able to keep a consistent description in these sorts of situations in which matter undergoes large quantum fluctuations. This is one reason many physicists believe gravity is indeed quantized.

Does this mean that General Relativity is indeterminate or inconsistent? I wouldn't say so. Notice that I needed to adapt the Einstein equations (one of the hallmarks of Relativity) to consider quantum matter. The Einstein equations simply do not make sense if you consider quantum matter, because the object $T_{ab}$ is not defined for quantum matter. You can define $\hat{T}_{ab}$, and you can define $\langle \hat{T}_{ab} \rangle$, but $T_{ab}$ is completely meaningless.

If you consider the simpler case in which there is only experimental uncertainty in, e.g., the position of an object, yes, you'll have an experimental uncertainty in the gravitational field. This is true to any theory of physics and does not mean the theory is indeterminate. Even if your system at some point in time is described by a probability distribution, we can still evolve this probability deterministically, in the sense that we can obtain the correct probability distribution at any other point in time. We might not be able to know the exact result of a measurement, but we know the possible results and how often each of them come out. This is true in both classical and quantum physics, and is the reason I think your first clarification point might be a bit badly written. Quantum physics intrinsically involves probabilities, but it is subject to well-defined evolution laws. The probabilities evolve in a deterministic way.

Shortly,

> Does the indeterminacy (uncertainty) of energy and momentum cause indeterminacy of gravity?

If you mean experimental uncertainty, yes, you'll need to propagate the uncertainties, just as with any other physical theory that ever existed. If you mean quantum uncertainty, the question doesn't make sense in the framework of General Relativity. However, if we consider a semiclassical analysis, it is really difficult to imagine how to reconcile a classical gravitational field with a quantum source, leading physicists to believe that gravity is indeed quantum (some physicists might still pursue the difficult task of keeping gravity classical, though).

Comment: per "If you mean quantum uncertainty, the question doesn't make sense in the framework of General Relativity. " Given that the calculations of mass are integral for general relativity, I do not see how my question doesn't make sense within the framework of relativity. Other than that, I greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: I added some words to the question that I hope make it clearer.

Comment: @JamesGoetz Energy, mass, and momentum in quantum mechanics are not real numbers, but operators. However, what enters the right hand side of the classical Einstein equations should be a tensor made of real numbers. This tensor is not defined in quantum mechanics. If your matter is quantum, you can get an operator and its expectation value. Hence, you need to modify GR to account for quantum matter

Comment: Furthermore, concerning your edit, General Relativity does not work only with the mass of an object, Instead, it uses energy and momentum directly (mass *is* energy in Relativity, and momentum is also a source of gravity).

Comment: Being more direct: "I do not see how my question doesn't make sense within the framework of relativity". Your question asks about quantum matter. Quantum matter can't give one of the inputs required by GR, only a related notion. There is a natural way to answer the question, but it requires a gentle modification of Einstein's equation, hence departing from GR and moving towards semiclassical gravity